# Cannot mock BluetoothGattCharacteristic.addDescriptor method

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking

I am trying to write a test for a method which call BluetoothGattCharacteristic.addDescriptor method. For some reason I can't mock this method in order to write a test. I am still new to the mocking world but after hours of googling I can't find what I am doing wrong.

I tried to mock it with Mockito and with PowerMock and no luck.

###### Method which is being tested:

```
object Profile {
...
    fun createTheService(): BluetoothGattService
    {
        val service = BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY)

        // state characteristic
        val statePropertyMask = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY or BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE
        val configDescriptor = BluetoothGattDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID, statePropertyMask)
        val charaState = BluetoothGattCharacteristic(stateCharaUUID, statePropertyMask, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE)
    
        charaState.addDescriptor(configDescriptor)
       ...
    }
...
}
```

###### TestClass:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Profile::class)
class ProfileTest {

    private lateinit var mockedBluetoothGattCharacteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mockedBluetoothGattCharacteristic = mock(BluetoothGattCharacteristic::class.java)
   }

    @Test
    fun createTheService() {
        `when`(
            mockedBluetoothGattCharacteristic.addDescriptor(
                any(BluetoothGattDescriptor::class.java)
            )
        ).thenReturn(false)

        assertEquals(1, Profile.createTheService())

    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Method addDescriptor in android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method addDescriptor in android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.addDescriptor(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.java)
    at ....bluetooth.Profile.createTheService(Profile.kt:57)
    at ....bluetooth.ProfileTest.createTheService(ProfileTest.kt:109)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
```

Comment: why even test this ? are you not testing built-in functionality now ? seems a bit pointless

Comment: I would like to test createTheService method which has some additional steps I didn't include in the code. My point is that I would like to know why I can't mock this and not really if the test is pointless since my goal is to learn how to do mocking